# unicode to Ascii API

Tags: blackberry

Hi I am developing an application to display Indian language in application. The text that i use in my application is in Unicode format. I would like to know how can I convert these unicode to ASCII so that I can Display them on my application

Comment: Do you know algorithm that represents unicode to ascii without heart for reader? Also BB already could present Unicode except some old models and certain languages

Answer (score 3):

[Malyalam Unicode](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0D00.pdf&ei=IJhEUM6tDofMrQeOuID4BQ&usg=AFQjCNGIaFdnxwnWcGW1A1SJZixtAFqfJw)

The font file has wrong unicodes for the malyalam characters, using the font editor you need to write the corresponding malyalam unicodes and then it might work properly..

Comment: the font file containing Malayalam characters only

Answer (score 1):

But why do you need to convert into ASCII? You can directily show unicodes and it would get converted to corresponding language..
Please see this link, i guess this would help:

[See this at blackberry forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Display-hindi-characters-in-blackberry-os-5-0-application/td-p/1838681/page/2)

Comment: I have already tried this but the device is not showing Equalent Malayalam text for Unicode

Comment: The link given for the font editor in the above link verifies if the corresponding unicodes are correct for the malyalam character. I think the font file you are using has wrong unicodes for the actual malyalam characters.

Comment: the font i used is kaumudi.ttf

Comment: can you provide me the link to download the file??

Comment: It might be also the file has wrong encoding i think for corresponding malyalam unicodes, check that using font editor